Unable to Read Binary Data from Smart Card After Successful BAC - “File Not Found” Error
I am working on a smart card application where I successfully connect to the card using keys derived from the MRZ through the Basic Access Control (BAC) process. I am able to select the Data Group (DG) and receive the response code 9000, which indicates success. However, I encounter a “File Not Found” (6A82) error when trying to read the binary data.
What I Have Done:

Calculated SEED from MRZ Data, and derived kEnc and kMac keys using the MRZ information (document number, date of birth, and date of expiry).

Successfully select the applet using the correct AID and receive a 9000 status code.

Performed Basic Authentication. This step is completed successfully, and I receive the card’s challenge code.

Selected Data Group (DG), and wrapped the APDU command using kEnc and kMac derived from the MRZ, but when sending the wrapped SELECT command to the card, I receive the 6A82 - File Not Found error.


Relevant Code:
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.KeyException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

public class TrusKYC {
// Other methods 
    // Example MRZ inputs
    private static final String DOCUMENT_NUMBER = "789XXXXX";                       // Document number     
    private static final String DATE_OF_BIRTH   = "XXXXXX";                         // Date of birth (YYMMDD format)
    private static final String DATE_OF_EXPIRY  = "XXXXXX";                         // Date of expiry (YYMMDD format)
    private static final String AID         = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; // AID

private static byte[] ssc; // Send Sequence Counter as a byte array
    
    /**
     * Calculates the SEED from the MRZ data by hashing it with SHA-1.
     *
     * @param documentNumber The document number (padded to 9 characters if necessary).
     * @param dateOfBirth The date of birth in YYMMDD format.
     * @param dateOfExpiry The date of expiry in YYMMDD format.
     * @return The first 16 bytes of the SHA-1 hash, which forms the SEED.
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException if SHA-1 algorithm is not available.
     */
    public static byte[] calculateSeed(String documentNumber, String dateOfBirth, String dateOfExpiry) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        // Pad the document number to 9 characters with '<' if necessary
        documentNumber = String.format("%-9s", documentNumber).replace(' ', '<');

        // Concatenate MRZ information
        String mrzInfo = documentNumber + dateOfBirth + dateOfExpiry;
        System.out.println("MRZ Info: " + mrzInfo);

        // Calculate SHA-1 hash of the concatenated MRZ string
        MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        byte[] hash = sha1.digest(mrzInfo.getBytes());

        // Extract the first 16 bytes to form the SEED
        byte[] seed = Arrays.copyOf(hash, 16);
        return seed;
    }

    /**
     * Converts a byte array to a hexadecimal string representation.
     *
     * @param bytes The byte array to convert.
     * @return The hexadecimal string representation of the byte array.
     */
    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }    

    /**
     * Derives kEnc and kMac from the provided SEED.
     *
     * @param seed The 16-byte SEED derived from the MRZ.
     * @return An array containing kEnc and kMac as SecretKey objects.
     * @throws KeyException If there is an issue with key generation or parity adjustment.
     */
    public static SecretKey[] deriveKeys(byte[] seed) throws KeyException {
        if (seed.length != 16) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("SEED must be 16 bytes long.");
        }

        // Split SEED into two halves
        byte[] leftHalf = Arrays.copyOfRange(seed, 0, 8);  // First 8 bytes
        byte[] rightHalf = Arrays.copyOfRange(seed, 8, 16); // Last 8 bytes

        // Create kEnc by repeating leftHalf and adjusting key parity
        byte[] kEncBytes = adjustParity(concat(leftHalf, leftHalf)); // 16 bytes
        SecretKey kEnc = create3DESKey(kEncBytes);

        // Create kMac by repeating rightHalf and adjusting key parity
        byte[] kMacBytes = adjustParity(concat(rightHalf, rightHalf)); // 16 bytes
        SecretKey kMac = create3DESKey(kMacBytes);

        return new SecretKey[]{kEnc, kMac};
    }

    /**
     * Adjusts the parity of a DES key to ensure each byte has an odd number of 1-bits.
     *
     * @param keyBytes The byte array representing the key.
     * @return The key with adjusted parity.
     */
    private static byte[] adjustParity(byte[] keyBytes) {
        for (int i = 0; i < keyBytes.length; i++) {
            int parity = Integer.bitCount(keyBytes[i] & 0xFF) % 2; // Calculate parity (even or odd)
            if (parity == 0) { // Even parity detected, adjust to make it odd
                keyBytes[i] ^= 1; // Flip the least significant bit
            }
        }
        return keyBytes;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a 3DES key from a byte array, ensuring it is suitable for Triple DES operations.
     *
     * @param keyBytes The 16-byte array representing the 3DES key.
     * @return A SecretKey object suitable for 3DES encryption.
     * @throws KeyException If the key cannot be created.
     */
    private static SecretKey create3DESKey(byte[] keyBytes) throws KeyException {
        try {
            // DESedeKeySpec for 3DES expects a 24-byte key, so we pad the 16-byte key to 24 bytes
            byte[] paddedKey = new byte[24];
            System.arraycopy(keyBytes, 0, paddedKey, 0, 16);
            System.arraycopy(keyBytes, 0, paddedKey, 16, 8); // Reuse the first 8 bytes

            // Create a SecretKey using DESedeKeySpec
            DESedeKeySpec spec = new DESedeKeySpec(paddedKey);
            SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
            return keyFactory.generateSecret(spec);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new KeyException("Failed to create 3DES key: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Concatenates two byte arrays into one.
     *
     * @param first  The first byte array.
     * @param second The second byte array.
     * @return The concatenated byte array.
     */
    private static byte[] concat(byte[] first, byte[] second) {
        byte[] result = new byte[first.length + second.length];
        System.arraycopy(first, 0, result, 0, first.length);
        System.arraycopy(second, 0, result, first.length, second.length);
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Converts a hexadecimal string to a byte array.
     *
     * @param hex The hexadecimal string.
     * @return The byte array.
     */
    public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String hex) {
        int length = hex.length();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 2) {
            bytes[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(hex.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                    + Character.digit(hex.charAt(i + 1), 16));
        }
        return bytes;
    }

    /**
     * Sends an APDU command to the Proxmark3 device and captures the response.
     *
     * @param command      The APDU command to send (as a hexadecimal string).
     * @param description  A description of the command being sent.
     * @param wrappedCommand If true, the command will be wrapped using secure messaging.
     * @return The response from the Proxmark3 device.
     */
    public static String sendApduCommand(String command, String description) {
        try {

            System.out.println("Sending " + description + " command: " + command);

            // Construct the command to be sent to Proxmark3
            String[] pm3Command = {
                    "/opt/homebrew/bin/proxmark3",
                    "/dev/tty.usbmodem1101", // Change this to match your actual device port
                    "-c",
                    "hf 14a apdu -s -d " + command
            };

            // Use ProcessBuilder to execute the command
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(pm3Command);
            processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true); // Merge stderr with stdout

            // Start the process
            Process process = processBuilder.start();

            // Capture the output from the command
            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
                StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    output.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                // Wait for the process to complete
                process.waitFor();
                System.out.println(output.toString());
                return output.toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error sending APDU command: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String getChallengeCode(String log) {
        // Regular expression to capture the challenge code ending with 9000
        String regex = "\\b([A-F0-9]+9000)\\b";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(log);

        // Find and print the challenge code
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String challengeCode = matcher.group(1);
            challengeCode = challengeCode.substring(0, challengeCode.length() - 4); 
            System.out.println("Challenge code received: " + challengeCode);
            
            return challengeCode;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Challenge code not found.");
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generates an 8-byte reader challenge (rndIFD) using SecureRandom.
     *
     * @return An 8-byte random challenge generated by the reader.
     */
    private static byte[] generateReaderChallenge() {
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] rndIFD = new byte[8];
        random.nextBytes(rndIFD);
        System.out.println("Generated Reader Challenge (rndIFD): " + bytesToHex(rndIFD));
        return rndIFD;
    }

    /**
     * Computes the Send Sequence Counter (SSC) by combining the last 4 bytes of rndICC and rndIFD.
     *
     * @param rndICC The random challenge from the card.
     * @param rndIFD The random challenge from the reader.
     * @return The SSC as a long value.
     */
    public static long computeSendSequenceCounter(byte[] rndICC, byte[] rndIFD) {
        if (rndICC == null || rndICC.length != 8 || rndIFD == null || rndIFD.length != 8) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Wrong length input");
        }
        long ssc = 0;
        for (int i = 4; i < 8; i++) {
            ssc <<= 8;
            ssc += rndICC[i] & 0xFF;
        }
        for (int i = 4; i < 8; i++) {
            ssc <<= 8;
            ssc += rndIFD[i] & 0xFF;
        }
        return ssc;
    }
    
    /**
     * Converts the SSC from long to a byte array.
     *
     * @param value The SSC as a long.
     * @return The SSC as an 8-byte array.
     */
    private static byte[] longToByteArray(long value) {
        byte[] result = new byte[8];
        for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
            result[i] = (byte) (value & 0xFF);
            value >>= 8;
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    /**
     * Increments the Send Sequence Counter (SSC).
     */
    private static void incrementSSC() {
        for (int i = ssc.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (++ssc[i] != 0) break;
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Pads the data to a multiple of 8 bytes.
     *
     * @param data The data to be padded.
     * @return The padded data.
     */
    private static byte[] padData(byte[] data) {
        int paddingLength = 8 - (data.length % 8);
        byte[] paddedData = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length + paddingLength);
        Arrays.fill(paddedData, data.length, paddedData.length, (byte) paddingLength);
        return paddedData;
    }
    
    /**
     * Encrypts the data field of the APDU using 3DES and CBC mode.
     *
     * @param data The data to be encrypted.
     * @param kEnc The encryption key (kEnc).
     * @return The encrypted data.
     * @throws Exception If encryption fails.
     */
    private static byte[] encryptData(byte[] data, SecretKey kEnc) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/NoPadding");
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]); // IV is usually zero for the first command
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, kEnc, iv);
        return cipher.doFinal(padData(data));
    }
    
    /**
     * Generates a MAC over the APDU command and encrypted data using kMac.
     *
     * @param apdu The original APDU command.
     * @param encryptedData The encrypted data field.
     * @param kMac The MAC key (kMac).
     * @return The MAC.
     * @throws Exception If MAC generation fails.
     */
    private static byte[] generateMAC(byte[] apdu, byte[] encryptedData, SecretKey kMac) throws Exception {
        // Create a message digest to combine SSC, APDU header, and encrypted data
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        md.update(ssc);
        md.update(apdu, 0, 5); // Header
        md.update(encryptedData);
        byte[] hash = md.digest();

        // Pad the hash to make its length a multiple of 8 bytes before encryption
        byte[] paddedHash = padData(hash);

        // Encrypt the padded hash using kMac to create the MAC
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/NoPadding");
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]); // Zero IV for the first message
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, kMac, iv);
        return cipher.doFinal(paddedHash); // Encrypt the padded hash
    }
    
    /**
     * Wraps the APDU command with secure messaging using kEnc and kMac.
     *
     * @param apdu The original APDU command.
     * @param kEnc The encryption key (kEnc).
     * @param kMac The MAC key (kMac).
     * @return The wrapped APDU command with secure messaging.
     * @throws Exception If there is an error in encryption or MAC calculation.
     */
    public static byte[] wrapAPDU(byte[] apdu, SecretKey kEnc, SecretKey kMac) throws Exception {
        // Increment SSC
        incrementSSC();

        // Encrypt the data field of the APDU using kEnc
        byte[] dataField = Arrays.copyOfRange(apdu, 5, apdu.length); // Extract data field
        byte[] encryptedData = encryptData(dataField, kEnc);

        // Generate MAC over the APDU header and encrypted data
        byte[] mac = generateMAC(apdu, encryptedData, kMac);

        // Construct the wrapped APDU: Header + Encrypted Data + MAC
        byte[] wrappedAPDU = new byte[apdu.length - dataField.length + encryptedData.length + mac.length];
        System.arraycopy(apdu, 0, wrappedAPDU, 0, 5); // APDU Header
        System.arraycopy(encryptedData, 0, wrappedAPDU, 5, encryptedData.length); // Encrypted Data
        System.arraycopy(mac, 0, wrappedAPDU, 5 + encryptedData.length, mac.length); // MAC

        return wrappedAPDU;
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // 01 Calculate the SEED from MRZ data
            byte[] seed = calculateSeed(DOCUMENT_NUMBER, DATE_OF_BIRTH, DATE_OF_EXPIRY);
            System.out.println("01 SEED: " + bytesToHex(seed));

            // 02 Derive kEnc and kMac from the SEED
            SecretKey[] keys = deriveKeys(seed);
            String kEncHex = bytesToHex(keys[0].getEncoded());
            String kMacHex = bytesToHex(keys[1].getEncoded());
            System.out.println("02 kEnc: " + kEncHex);
            System.out.println("02 kMac: " + kMacHex);

            // 03 Connect To Card and Select Applet
            System.out.println("03 Connect To Card and Select Applet");
            String command = AID;
            String response = sendApduCommand(command, "Select Applet"); // Set wrappedCommand to true if wrapping is needed
            //ystem.out.println("03 Card Response>>" + response+"<<");

            // Regular expression to match the status 9000
            String regex = "<<<\\s*9000\\b";

            // Compile the pattern
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

            // Create a matcher for the given log string
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(response);

            // Check if the pattern matches
            if (matcher.find()) {
                // Proceed with your program
                System.out.println("03 Connected to Applet Successfully");

                // 04 Do Basic Authentication using Mrz Derived key

                // Convert hex strings to byte arrays
                byte[] kEncBytes = hexStringToByteArray(kEncHex);
                byte[] kMacBytes = hexStringToByteArray(kMacHex);

                // Create SecretKey objects for kEnc and kMac
                SecretKey kEnc = create3DESKey(kEncBytes);
                SecretKey kMac = create3DESKey(kMacBytes);

                command = "0084000008" +  bytesToHex(seed);
                response = sendApduCommand(command, "Perform Basic Authentication"); // Set wrappedCommand to true if wrapping is needed
                //ystem.out.println("03 Card Response>>" + response+"<<");

                String challengeCode = getChallengeCode(response);
                if (challengeCode != null) {
                    // Card challenge (rndICC) and Reader challenge (rndIFD)
                    byte[] rndICC = hexStringToByteArray(challengeCode); // Card challenge
                    
                    // Generate Reader challenge (rndIFD) programmatically
                    byte[] rndIFD = generateReaderChallenge(); // Generate the 8-byte random reader challenge
                    
                    long sscLong = computeSendSequenceCounter(rndICC, rndIFD);
                    System.out.println("SSC: " + Long.toHexString(sscLong).toUpperCase());
                    
                    // Initialize SSC as a byte array
                    ssc = longToByteArray(sscLong); // Correctly assign SSC as a byte array
                                                         
                    // Example APDU command to select DG 00A4020C02011C
                    byte[] selectDG1 = new byte[]{(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xA4, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x0C, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x1C}; 

                    // Increment SSC before wrapping the SELECT command               
                    // Wrap the APDU command with secure messaging
                    byte[] wrappedSelectDG1 = wrapAPDU(selectDG1, kEnc, kMac);
                    System.out.println("Wrapped SELECT APDU: " + bytesToHex(wrappedSelectDG1));
                    
                    // Send the wrapped APDU to the card and handle the response
                    response = sendApduCommand(bytesToHex(wrappedSelectDG1), "Selecting DG Group 1");
                                    
                    /*
                    // Example READ BINARY command to read 8 bytes from the selected DG at offset 0
                    byte[] readBinary = new byte[]{(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xB0, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x08}; // 00B0000008
                    
                    // Increment SSC before wrapping the READ BINARY command
                    incrementSSC();
                    byte[] wrappedReadBinary = wrapAPDU(readBinary, kEnc, kMac); // Wrap the READ BINARY command
                    System.out.println("Wrapped READ BINARY APDU: " + bytesToHex(wrappedReadBinary));
*/
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Basic Authentication Failed");
                }

            } else {
                // Handle the error or take alternative action
                System.out.println("Unable to connect to card");
            }

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            System.out.println("SHA-1 algorithm not available.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyException e) {
            System.out.println("Error deriving keys: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error wrapping APDU: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

Below is the debugging log.
MRZ Info: 789XXX<XXXX14260801
01 SEED: 8450E2185D6C8B994480B91C819BE645
02 kEnc: 8551E3195D6D8A988551E3195D6D8A988551E3195D6D8A98
02 kMac: 4580B91C809BE6454580B91C809BE6454580B91C809BE645
03 Connect To Card and Select Applet
Sending Select Applet command
[=] Session log /Users/XXXX/.proxmark3/logs/log_20240831110644.txt
[+] loaded `/Users/XXXX/.proxmark3/preferences.json`
[+] execute command from commandline: hf 14a apdu -s -d 00A404000AAXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

[+] Using UART port /dev/tty.usbmodem1101
[+] Communicating with PM3 over USB-CDC
[usb|script] pm3 --> hf 14a apdu -s -d 00A404000AAXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[+] select card
[+] >>> 00A404000AAXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[+] <<< 9000 | ..
[+] <<< status: 90 00 - Command successfully executed (OK).

03 Connected to Applet Successfully
Sending Perform Basic Authentication command: 00840000088450E2185D6C8B994480B91C819BE645
[=] Session log /Users/XXXX/.proxmark3/logs/log_20240831110645.txt
[+] loaded `/Users/XXXX/.proxmark3/preferences.json`
[+] execute command from commandline: hf 14a apdu -s -d 00840000088450E2185D6C8B994480B91C819BE645

[+] Using UART port /dev/tty.usbmodem1101
[+] Communicating with PM3 over USB-CDC
[usb|script] pm3 --> hf 14a apdu -s -d 00840000088450E2185D6C8B994480B91C819BE645
[+] select card
[+] >>> 00840000088450E2185D6C8B994480B91C819BE645
[+] <<< 2C01AC4881E042879000 | ,..H..B...
[+] <<< status: 90 00 - Command successfully executed (OK).

Challenge code received: 2C01AC4881E04287
Generated Reader Challenge (rndIFD): 3CE5BB24E7779089
SSC: 81E04287E7779089
Wrapped SELECT APDU: 00A400000207778C10DBAC70B138EA22FD6CE03DE9D04BADD3A24D23DDA705FE8ED935AE21
Sending Selecting DG Group 1 command: 00A400000207778C10DBAC70B138EA22FD6CE03DE9D04BADD3A24D23DDA705FE8ED935AE21
[=] Session log /Users/XXXX/.proxmark3/logs/log_20240831110647.txt
[+] loaded `/Users/XXXX/.proxmark3/preferences.json`
[+] execute command from commandline: hf 14a apdu -s -d 00A400000207778C10DBAC70B138EA22FD6CE03DE9D04BADD3A24D23DDA705FE8ED935AE21

[+] Using UART port /dev/tty.usbmodem1101
[+] Communicating with PM3 over USB-CDC
[usb|script] pm3 --> hf 14a apdu -s -d 00A400000207778C10DBAC70B138EA22FD6CE03DE9D04BADD3A24D23DDA705FE8ED935AE21
[+] select card
[+] >>> 00A400000207778C10DBAC70B138EA22FD6CE03DE9D04BADD3A24D23DDA705FE8ED935AE21
[+] <<< 6A82 | j.
[+] <<< status: 6A 82 - File not found

Problem:
Despite correctly wrapping the APDU commands with secure messaging, I am unable to read the binary data after selecting the Data Group (DG). The “File Not Found” error suggests that the secure messaging may not be correctly applied or there might be an issue with the command structure.
What I’ve Tried:

Verified that the APDU commands are correctly wrapped.

Ensured that the SSC (Send Sequence Counter) is correctly incremented before wrapping commands.

Checked that the card response status is 9000 before reading data, indicating a successful connection.


Questions:

How can I modify the existing code to successfully select the Data Group and read the binary data?

Are there any additional steps or considerations for correctly wrapping and sending APDU commands with secure messaging in this context?


Any insights or suggestions are appreciated!

I don't understand the log that well. First of all, it looks as if you were trying to perform BAC but I don't see the External Authenticate command, I can only see Get Challenge so it looks to me as if BAC was not performed at all. Second, the wrapped APDU looks weird to me since the CLA byte doesn't indicate secure messaging and the command data field does not contain secure messaging data objects as specified by ICAO. Also, can you tell me what is the AID of the DG you are trying to select?

Would you please recommend any Java samples to do the BAC and read DG? I may not doing it in the proper way.

I’m voting to close this question because this show a misunderstanding of BAC, and the current code can never work without MUTUAL AUTHENTICATE. Please look at the Technical Report that specifies BAC for examples of the APDU's as well as the calculations.
